# UINavigationControl with Image View as root, table views thereafter

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller

This is one that should be simple, but since I'm rather new to the xcode IOS 4 developement, I gotta ask:

What I need:  an Image View with a button that will then display a series of linked table views.  This screams (to me) a UINavigationController where the first view is NOT a table view, but the UIImage view.  I cannot get this to work.

Using the NavigationControl project, xcode insists on the first view being a table view.  Not what I want.  If I use a Window based view and put an image view as the root, attempts to make the secondary view a table view results in it ignoring my data source delegate methods.

Can anyone present a simple/bare bones solution that works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should be simple.

In your ApplicationDelegate, there should be a line like this:

```
MyImageViewController *myImageViewController = [[MyImageViewController alloc] init];
self.navigationController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootView:myImageViewController] autorelease];
```

Then, when you want to push another UITableViewController, you can just create push and set delegate to it.

`[self.navigationController pushViewController:myTableViewController];`

For the delegate and datasource, is your `MyTableViewController` class inherits from `UITableViewController` and conforms to `UITableViewDelegate`, `UITableViewDataSource`?

That's all I can say without code

Comment: Thanks!  I did manage to solve the problem -- with a combination of your help, and additional insight to errors (don't believe what one sees in interface builder).

Comment: There is a white V mark under my answer, you can tick on that